# How to make a bottomSheet like YouTube comment?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

I know how to make a BottomSheet on Android.

It's a way to write `<app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.bottomsheetBehavior">` on the Layout in CoordinatorLayout.
It's a way that a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

However, it doesn't work like a YouTube comment.

If I scroll through the item in the RecyclerView, BottomSheet fold or unfold.

I want the bottomSheet to be fixed, If I scroll through the RecyclerView.
I want the bottom sheet to fold, If I drag the Draggable view, How do I implement it?

[image]

I'm working like this.
https://blog.naver.com/cheol1201/222721095977

Comment: why don't you add fixed size ?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior` to the child layout and set `behavior_peekHeight` to 800dp to hide the white space that appears after adding layout_behavior like this example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BottomSheetExampleFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="800dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView19"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Comments section"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_description" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_close" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:background="#C8C8C8" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_comments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]